# How to disable the error sound using the terminal?

Tags: ubuntu

It's a kind of plob sound. It's not created by the PC speakers, it goes through normal audio output. It happens for example when I hit autocomplete and there is either no or more then one result. It drives me nuts. I have to use the terminal because I use i3. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: There is nothing about i3 that would require you to use the terminal... but _which_ terminal app are you using specifically?

Comment: Please post your question in askubuntu.com

Comment: @grawity I tried both gnome terminal and xterm. Gnome Settings doesn't open under i3.

Comment: @SrinivasV while this question may be better answered on AskUbuntu, we do not advise people to cross post. If necessary the community can vote to move the question over there.